# gcc compiler not recognizing iterator substraction

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading, const-iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // for iterators
#include <list> // for lists
using namespace std;

void printReverse(const list<int>& lst) {
    using iterator = list<int>::const_iterator;
    iterator iter = lst.begin();
    iterator end_iter = lst.end();
    iterator mid = iter - (end_iter - iter)/2;
}
```

Does someone know why the gcc compiler reports an issue "error: invalid operands to binary expression ('iterator' (aka '__list_const_iterator<int, void *>') and 'iterator')" on line 5 where I try to calculate the difference between two iterators?

Comment: for the question: `std::distance`, but you should really think about doing random access on a list.

Comment: Please remove the line numbers. They are not helpful when we try to run your code.

Comment: There are different kinds of iterators with different characteristics. They don't necessarily all support binary subtraction.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the nodes in a linked list will have increasing pointer values.  The nodes can be located *anywhere* in memory.  Thus substraction will be an undefined or meaningless operation.

Answer (score 1):

The class template `std::list` does not have random access iterators. It has bidirectional iterators for which the `operator -` is not defined.

In any case this expression

```
iterator mid = iter - (end_iter - iter)/2;
                   ^^^^
```

does not make a sense.

You could write for example

```
iterator mid = std::next( std::begin( lst ), lst.size() / 2 );
```